# Disabling of sprite rotation during motion

Tags: c++, box2d, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2d-x and Box2d, how can I prevent my body from rotating
during falling, jumping or moving forward or backward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b2Body *body;  
body->SetFixedRotation(true);
```

See docs here :

https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h#350

Comment: There is one more question how can i limited the moving area of sprite in screen??

Comment: You need to set world boundaries. Check out Box2D test in sample test projects.

Comment: Sir I could't found. Where can i saw "world boundaries".Kindly elaborate it.

Comment: are you mean box2dEdges?